# Identifying the alias of a factor using Excel

Tags: excel

[image]

Hello, I would like to know a straight forward way to ID the alias of these factors.

Basically, the way we find the aliases are found by the Generator I = ABCD and then you multiply (mod 2) a factor.

For example, ID = ABCD^2 so D = ABC,  or IC = ABC^2D so C = ABD as shown in the table on row 10 to 14.

Using Excel, I would like to have the actual factor on row 15.

For example, I want cell B15 to be BCD, cell c15 to be ACD, etc.

I am a beginner in Excel but I am trying to learn.
I would appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your requirement then it looks like you just get the "factor" if the value in the corresponding row = 1.

[image]

If my understanding is correct then add the below code to a new module in the VBA Editor and it will work with the corresponding formula as shown in the image above.

```
Public Function GetFactorText(ByVal rngDeterminants As Range, ByVal rngFactors As Range) As String
    Dim lngRow As Long

    For lngRow = 1 To rngDeterminants.Rows.Count
        If rngDeterminants.Cells(lngRow, 1) = 1 Then GetFactorText = GetFactorText & rngFactors.Cells(lngRow, 1)
    Next
End Function
```

I attempted with an array formula but I failed dismally.  I'm sure it's possible that way but I'm not quite there with that solution.  Hopefully someone else can stump up that solution.

If the VBA solution doesn't help you then you can apply this formula and it will work for you.  It's not as nice or scalable as an array formula or the VBA approach but this will work ...

```
=IF(B10=1,$A$10,"") & IF(B11=1,$A$11,"") & IF(B12=1,$A$12,"") & IF(B13=1,$A$13,"") & IF(B14=1,$A$14,"")
```

... apply that formula to cell **B15** and fill across to the right.

Anyway, I hope that helps.

Comment: You do understand what I am trying to do.  I am glad.  It is just that using VBA is way beyond my understanding.  The idea is to extract the values from A1:A5 depending on whether the value of the cell is 1 or 0, but I don't know what function would do that. Even if I did, I would not know the function that would connect those letters extracted from the number.

Comment: @hyg17, yeah, that was the whole point of my solution.  We can simplify it with a formula that you can apply if that makes you happy.  I've updated my answer.